# TabBar remains hidden despite setting tabbar.hidden = NO in controller

Tags: ios, iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I currently have two view controllers, a `CameraViewController` that uses the imagePicker to take photos, and a `PhotoInboxViewController` that shows all the photo messages a person has received. `PhotoInboxViewController`, as well as my root view controller, is a `Tab Bar Controller`.

When I present the imagePicker in `CameraViewController` , as well as the image preview screen that follows it, I  disable the TabBar by setting `self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES`. My issue is, when `PhotoInboxViewController` is then shown again (for example, if the user cancels taking a photo), I would want the Tab Bar to be **shown**  again. In my `viewWillAppear` method in I have the following:

```
//In PhotoInboxViewController
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if ([[[self tabBarController] tabBar] isHidden]){
        self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = NO;
    }

}
```

In debugging, I see that the `if` statement is indeed evaluated as tabBar as `isHidden`, and therefore the next line is executed as well.  However, my Tab Bar remains hidden.

What am I doing incorrectly? Your help is appreciated - thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is a need for the `if ([[[self tabBarController] tabBar] isHidden])`. Try setting the hidden to 'NO' anyway.

Comment: Thanks - I took out the `if`, and am still having this issue.

Comment: Can't you change it back to visible in the `CameraViewController` class, after the cancel button is clicked?

Comment: How are you presenting the picker? Why do you need to hide the tab bar?

Comment: @Wain the picker is presented modally as `[self presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:NO completion:nil];`.  I choose to hide the tab bar because I want the image and image preview to take up the entire space of the screen.

Comment: @xicocaio thanks for the suggestion. I did indeed try that at several places, as well as reenabling the Tab Bar to be shown in `viewWillDisappear`.  However, the Tab Bar is still not shown this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to hide the tab bar. When presenting modally you should present from the full screen / root view controller. In this case the tab bar controller, not the view controller 'in' one of the tabs. This allows the presentation to work properly without any strange side effects.